# how can I call AutoIT UDF within Java

Tags: java, autoit

My query is how do I call the various UDF (user defined functions) of autoIT in Java using COM (component object model) just like the sample code mentioned below:

somewhat like this:

```
 File file = new File("lib" , "jacob-1.18-x64.dll");
 System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

 AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
 x.run("calc.exe");
 x.winActivate("Calculator");
 x.winWaitActive("Calculator");
 //Enter 3
 x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "133") ;
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 //Enter +
 x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "93") ;
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 //Enter 3
 x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "133") ;
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 //Enter =
 x.controlClick("Calculator", "", "121") ;
```

Comment: What u need to do? can u avoid it?

Comment: I need to open an Excel , Update and verify few cells , Then save it. I can't avoid it.

Comment: no need for autoit there. use apache poi or something similar to do such things with java

Comment: basically I am trying to automate browser related actions using selenium and non-browser related actions through AutoIT (in this case excel) but there are scenarios where I will not necessarily only be working with excel  but any number of windows application. My query is how do I call the various UDF (user defined functions) of autoIT in Java using COM (component object model) just like the sample code mentioned in the question.

Comment: When i was reading your question , it seems that you are using autoit for a browser. please read http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use existing AutoIt code using AutoItX. You have two options if you want to use AutoIt:

1. Compile an AutoIt script that does what you want and call it from your Java program.
2. Convert the UDF to Java/AutoItX

Comment: Thanks. **Options 1** - this is one possible solution but it does not give enough flexibility. **Option 2** - This is the one that I am looking for. Can you help how to I convert the UDF to Java/AutoITx.

Comment: It's not an easy option. Open up the UDF and start reimplementing the bits you need. AutoIT executables can be used to execute any autoit script, so you could always generate the script you need using Java and then execute it.

Comment: Thanks. could you please briefly mention the steps (not the actual code) of converting the UDF to java/AutoITx. As I am new to DLL and COM Interface.

Comment: It will depend on what you want to do, but I expect there will be quite a bit of work with the Windows API. It might be easier to do things directly in Java. e.g., for excel, see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074940/learn-java/java-app-dev-reading-and-writing-excel-spreadsheets.html