# How to run AutoIt script file (.au3) from C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, autoit, autoit-c#-wrapper

I've been trying to run an AutoIt script file (.au3) from my WPF application. It does not throw any error but does not work.

```
AutoItX.Run("test.au3", @"C:\Folder\",1);
```

But it works well with below line.

```
AutoItX.Run("calc.exe","",1);
```

Answer (score 1):

C# solution I have :

```
//switch vpn
Console.WriteLine("Refreshing VPN");
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " \"" + Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "RandomConnectProtonVpn.au3") + "\"";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoItX does not have the capability of running AutoIt scripts. To do that, you need to use the AutoIt interpreter, e.g. like:

```
AutoItX.Run(@"""C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe"" /AutoIt3ExecuteScript test.au3", @"C:\Folder\", 1);
```

Also see my answer here: [how can I call AutoIT UDF within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262545/how-can-i-call-autoit-udf-within-java/41304461#41304461)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by compiling the script into an .exe
(right click and compile with options and then choose .exe and compile.

1. `using System.Diagnostics;`
2. `Process.Start("path");`

Example:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\Downloads\\hello.exe");
```